# RuntimeException in a slide-show activity, using universal-image-loader

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, android-asynctask, handler

I am trying to create a slideshow, using 2 ImageViews and a set of transitions. I am using universal image loader for decoding the bitmaps, and everything works fine for 5-6 slides. After that, the activity freezes. The only exception I get from time to time in logcat is

```
12-11 17:36:16.545  22794-22794/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lucon.GrannyLauncher/com.lucon.GrannyLauncher.activities.Launcher}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030005
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030005
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
            at com.lucon.GrannyLauncher.activities.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The method I am using for creating the slideshow is this:

```
private void startSlideShow(){
    loadedViews.add(image1);
    loadedViews.add(image2);

    imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + slideShowData.getNextImagePath(), image1);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + slideShowData.getNextImagePath(), image2);

    final Handler transitionHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable transition = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Runnable that = this;
            ImageView currentView = loadedViews.peekFirst();
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + slideShowData.getNextImagePath(), currentView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    view.bringToFront();
                    view.startAnimation(animations.get(rand.nextInt(animations.size() - 1)));
                    loadedViews.add(((ImageView)view));
                    transitionHandler.postDelayed(that, 15000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    };
    transitionHandler.postDelayed(transition, 6000);
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this weird problem? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: the log cat is incomplete and i dont know what line is causing the null pointer error

Comment: sorry, I completed the logcat now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. I managed to fix it by taking a look at dalvik traces, when the app stopped responding.

I found this

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41388508 self=0x41066b78
  | sysTid=31195 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074868016
  | schedstat=( 43157155482 3673056299 23355 ) utm=4204 stm=111 core=1
  at java.util.LinkedList.contains(LinkedList.java:~488)
  at com.app.data.SlideShowData.getNextImagePath(SlideShowData.java:57)
  at com.app.custom.view.ImageSlideShow$1.run(ImageSlideShow.java:140)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:-1)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:-1)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:-1)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:-1)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:-1)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:-1)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I went to SlideShowData and discovered that because of a custom queue, the program got stuck into a while loop. Foolish mistake.

Comment: im glad you found it, i was just about to take a look at this post. 
anyways, have you tried extensively? are you sure its the same error, and no other one? i say it since in your log you can read ` Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030005` so it looks like a file is missing, or corrupted, or the format is not as expected, or whatever.  I hope it was actually the same and it is ok now!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. After I saw the traces files, I debugged extensively the method indicated and indeed it has problems. Thank you for your time :)!